# add 1 hour to timestamp in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ive got an excel sheet with a list of timestamps, they have come in with the wrong hour on them - they have ended up being an hour behind, how can update them ?

Each cell is formatted as `2013-05-24 17:05:04` and i want to update it to `2013-05-24 18:05:04`, ive tried splitting the time and date, adding one to the time and then `CONCATINATE` the two cells back together but it seems like a rather long way, is there something simpler ?

Comment: one hour sounds like a timezone problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `1/24` to the date.

1 day in excel is 1 unit, so 1 hour would be 1/24.

Answer (score 8):

If the time is in A1 then B1 should be =A1+TIME(1,0,0), then you can copy and paste values